# How do I change all the headers in 34 dataframes with a loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have successfully pulled in 31 '*.csv' files and created 31 dataframes with JupyterLab.  I was able to adjust the headers in one data frame as needed, but I dread having to apply individually.  As my database grows it will be entirely too tedious to adjust each header.

```
filenames = glob.glob('*.csv')
dataframes = [pd.read_csv(f) for f in filenames]
tlt = 'tlt.csv'
qqq = 'qqq.csv'
gld = 'gld.csv'
slv = 'slv.csv'
```

etc,etc

Code:

```
df_gold = pd.read_csv(gold, skiprows=[0], header=None)
header = df_gold.iloc[0]
df_gold = df_gold[1:]
df_gold.rename(columns = header)
df_gold.rename(columns={0:'Date', 1:'Open', 2:'High',3:'Low',4:'Close',5:'Volume'}, inplace=True)
print(df_gold.columns)
```

Output:

```
Index(['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume'], dtype='object')
```

My issue is that I would like to use a loop to apply the change in the headers to all dataframes used by this program.

TYIA

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like all dataframes have the same columns... do a loop as you suggested:

```
colnames = {0:'Date', 1:'Open', 2:'High', 3:'Low', 4:'Close'}
for i, df in enumerate(dataframes):
    dataframes[i] = df.drop(0, axis=0).rename(columns=colnames)
```

Answer (score 0):

If every CSV file has the same columns, then you could handle the column naming in the `read_csv()` function:

```
filenames = glob.glob('*.csv')
col_names = ['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']
dataframes = [
    pd.read_csv(f, header=0, names=col_names)
    for f in filenames
]
```

Comment: I did a combination of things, one of which was your suggestion.